# The Chernoff bound for continuous random variables.

Tags: probability, reference-request

In a paper I am reading, authors apply the Chernoff bound to a continuous random variable $X$ with positive mean: $$\mathbb{P}(X\le 0)\le \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X)]$$
I do not understand it. When I google for the Chernoff bound I get results for a sum of random variables that have values 0 or 1.
Could you please provide a reference where I can read about continuous case, or could you explain how to get above inequality. Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get it: Integrate the pointwise inequality $$\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant0}\leqslant\exp(\lambda X).$$ Note that, for this inequality to be true, one must assume that $\lambda\leqslant0$.

As explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#The_first_step_in_the_proof_of_Chernoff_bounds).

Answer (score 1):

$\Pr\left[X\geq0\right]=\Pr\left[e^{\lambda x}\geq1\right]\leq\frac{E\left[e^{\lambda x}\right]}{1}=E\left[e^{\lambda x}\right] $ Where the inequality follows from markov's inequality on the positive random variable $e^{\lambda x} $

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE, I see you've read the informed page and learnt about mathjax. You may consider adding more detail to your answer, but its still ok. Keep up the good work!